# Daycation vs overnight trip

Tags: meaning

Is a *daycation* the same as *an overnight trip*? Do they refer to the same amount of time for a very short holiday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I never heard of the word, Google gave me the definition in the second result: [MacMillan buzzword definition of daycation](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/daycation.html):

> daycation: 
>   a day trip or short holiday that does not involve staying away from home overnight

So no, it is not the same. Daycations are only a day, without staying away for a night.

Answer (score 0):

I might use "daycation" if I departed early in the morning and returned late in the evening of the same day.

I would use "overnight" trip if I returned the next day.